# How can I select a whole folder in vb.net open file dialog?

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to select the whole folder in VB.NET open dialog box?

By this I mean, open the dialog box and navigate through the folder and then select an entire folder not an individual file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't select a folder with the OpenFileDialog.  You can select a folder with the FolderBrowserDialog.

Are you looking to select all the files in a folder?  If so, use a FolderBrowserDialog to allow users to select a folder and call code similar to the following:

```
Dim files As String() = Directory.GetDirectories(folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
```

You can also go ahead and use an OpenFileDialog and set its Multiselect property to true.  This will allow your users the select more than one file in the dialog.

Does that answer your question?